# intuitive meaning of full derivative applied to a vector

Tags: real-analysis

let $Df(x_0)$ be a full derivative (linear mapping $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$) of a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ taken at the point $x_0$

Then what intuitive meaning of this derivative applied to a vector $x_1 \in R^n$: $[Df(x_0)]x_1$ is?

---

1)

For $m = 1$ we interpret this derivative $[D(f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R)(x_0)]$ as gradient of $f$ at point $x_0$ in $x_1$ direction, or get an angle between $x_1$ and grad. But for $m>1$ is this a "set of separate gradients of each of $m$ component-functions? (this is abstract interpretation) or does it have some 'bigger' or different meaning for $m>1$?

---

2)

what interpretation(in terms of 'bigger' or 'different' from a component-wise gradient) of higher order derivatives for $m>1$, like $D^2f(x_0)(x_1)$,  will be?

Comment: If $Df(x_0)$ is the derivative of a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ at a point $x_0$, then we can approximate the value of $f$ at a nearby point $x_0 + \Delta x$ using the following approximation: $f(x_0 + \Delta x) \approx f(x_0) + Df(x_0) \Delta x$. The approximation is good when $\Delta x$ is small. This is the key idea of calculus -- to take a complicated nonlinear function and approximate it locally by a linear function.

Comment: this property is inherent to the definition of the derivative. But I'm curious about what it means to apply $Df(x_0)$ to $x_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g(h)=h[Df(x_0)]x_1$, if $\Vert x_1 \Vert = 1$ and $h$ is a scalar variable, represents a line in $\mathbb{R}^m$, that is parallel to the line, $g^*(h)$, which approximates $f$ so well at $x_0$ in the direction given by $x_1$, such that $$f(x_0+hx_1)=g^*(h)+o(h)$$.